# Linq .Where() function always fail

Tags: c#, linq, telerik-grid

I am having an issue with Linq at the moment. We are using the Telerik controls in a WPF application in C#. I have am "array" of clients. The type of array is a QueryableEntityCoreCollectionView, which is from Telerik. This is the source of a gridview.

I now need to make a property which will return a subset of these clients. No matter what conditions I put in my Where clause, the Where fails and gives me the classic Object is not set to an Instance blahblahblah. (the grid is able to get a IEnumerable, so I don't have to convert back into a QueryableEntityCoreCollectionView at the end.

Here is a bit of code I am trying to play around with:

```
public IEnumerable<Client> FilteredClients {
            get {
                
                IEnumerable<Client> res1 = clients.AsEnumerable<Client>();
                IEnumerable<Client> res2 = res1.Where(T => 1 == 1);
                return res2;
            }
        }
```

In the above example, res1 contains 11 elements. res2 does not work. It goes over it, I don't receive an actual exception, but if I put a breakpoint on the return, and check out both res1 and res2, I can see res1 is okay, res2 when I open it's result view, I get the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." with the stack trace:

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Given the search criteria "1==1", I would expect everything to come out of it... But it fails. Even with a real search, like T => T.City == T.City, it also fails the same way. No matter what I give to Where(), it fails. If I simply return res1 here, my full list passes back to my datagrid as an IEnumerable, and everything works fine. As soon as I try to filter on anything, it fails.

Any ideas?

---

edit:
After Hazrelle comment, I tried calling .ToList() ... But everytime I try to do that, I get a Null Exception.

```
clients.ToList<Client>(); // fails
clients.AsEnumerable<Client>().ToList<Client>(); // fails
```

Everything I try fails, and I don't know why...

---

Edit 2: Still not able to filter or anything... However I got the following line of code to pass:

```
var query = clients.SourceCollection.ToEnumerable().First();
```

However, query is not a Client, but rather a Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableProxy , and is still seen as a collection with 11 items. It is NOT just the first Client.

Comment: The full stack trace should reveal which method the error comes from, either from Telerik or your own code. If it's from Telerik you should probably report it as a bug. Either way, I don't think we can do anything here.

Comment: How are you using your `FilteredClients`? Are you saving its return value someplace that will use it when `clients` is already null?

Comment: what happens when you do the filtering by iteration with a loop? It seems a little as the `QueryableEntityCoreCollectionView` has difficulties to relay the enumeration of the collection to a second variable. Is the data from the db already in `clients` ? or is it fetched every time when you access it like in `IQuerable` ? If it is the second case, then may be you would need to call `AsQueryable( )` instead

Comment: the [Telerik search for this type](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/search?q=QueryableEntityCoreCollectionView) yields no results

Comment: `Where` is probably not executed until you use `res2`. Append `.ToList()` after this should resolve your issue. Take care of [deferred execution](https://samwalpole.com/linq-beware-of-deferred-execution).

Comment: Gert: It happens during binding, I don't have any more stack to supply, thats what visual studio gives me.

GSerg: in used in the binding. But honestly it doesn't matter. The fact is that my clients list is there and fully filled. Linq explodes as I try to go through it.

Comment: Mong: I tried all permutations immaginable of AsQueryable, AsEnumerable, etc that you can imagine. However, I have discovered something else, see my answer to Hazrelle below. I know you searched on the Telerik site, but I can assure vidual studio tells me this is in Telerik.Windows.Data

Comment: Hazrelle: found something interesting, I am editing my original post, see in a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this QueryableEntityCoreCollectionView object is either bugged, or we are not supposed to play with it, and should only be handled internally by Telerik stuff, but I have resolved the problem by never creating this object, I create a good ol' List of Client directly and give this to the grid instead. Linq works like a charm then...

For some reason, no amount of AsEnumerable, ToList, AsWhatever I did to a QueryableEntityCoreCollectionView(of Client), it always became a QueryableEntityView(of Client) at best, never actually became a simple List(of Client).

Strange.

It is very possible I am loosing the ability to update the database by doing that, However, at this point, this is not data that is meant to be updateable, at least not from that window.